# How to use Redis aeCreateTimeEvent?

Tags: java, lua, redis

I am very new to Redis and we use LUA script and Redis in our project.

We would like to know how to use Redis `aeCreateTimeEvent` to call the Lua Function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Redis :)

`aeCreateTimeEvent` is an internal Redis server function that does not get exposed publicly. Moreover, there is no native way ATM to have Redis invoke Lua scripts (or any other command for that matter) in a user-configurable cron-like manner.

A simple solution would be to set up a worker process in your language of choice, that wakes up per your specified intervals and sends the command to Redis. This, however, has an administrative and operational overhead of maintaining that process.

An alternative that is possible starting with v4 is to use a module for that. In fact, here's a little hack that does just that: https://gist.github.com/itamarhaber/80244e4fde70032bf83b786ec67ed3db